# ASP.NET report with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure named "Graph" that should get a value to the parameter @Material, and I created a report in ASP.NET that should show a chart using the data from the stored procedure.

However, when I try to load the report I get:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'PhilipsMaterialsDataSet'.
>   ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'GetData' that has no parameters.

I tried different solutions but none of them worked. Also, I'm not sure if I should declare the parameter in the ASP code.

( by the way, GetData is not recognized here because it has one parameter (@Material-from the stored procedure) and for some reason, it is called without any parameters )

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;


public partial class StatisticsPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string Connectionstring = "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }

    }

   protected void btndisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindReport();
    }
    private void BindReport()
    {
        SSRSReport report = new SSRSReport();
        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
         new SqlParameter("@Material","453567068441")

      };
        string ReportDataSource = "DataSet1";
        bool bind = report.CreateReport(Connectionstring, "graph", sqlParams, ref ReportViewer1, ReportDataSource);
        if (bind)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}


public class SSRSReport
{


       public SSRSReport()
       {
              //
              // TODO: Add constructor logic here
              //
       }
    public bool CreateReport(String Connectionstring,string StoreProcedureName ,SqlParameter[] Parameter,ref  Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer,string ReportDataSource)
    {
        bool reportbind = false;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = StoreProcedureName;
            com.Parameters.AddRange(Parameter);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(ReportDataSource, ds.Tables[0]);
            if ( ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);





                //This is another solution I tried:





                //List<ReportParameter> lstReportParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
                //ReportParameter objReportParameter = new ReportParameter("Material", "453567068441");
                //lstReportParameters.Add(objReportParameter);
                //ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(lstReportParameters);
               // ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();

                reportbind = true;
            }                       
        }
       return  reportbind;
    }

}
```

The ASP code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StatisticsPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="StatisticsPage" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test SSRS</title>
</head>
<body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="610px" Width="1179px" ShowParameterPrompts="true">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc" >
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="PhilipsMaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.GraphTableAdapter" >
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
          </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the error mentioned, your `ObjectDataSource` is looking for the method `GetData`, which doesn't exist. You should probably take a look at how the `ObjectDataSource` actually works.

Comment: Why are you using `com.Parameters.AddRange(Parameter);` why not use `com.Parameters.AddWithValue()` method..? In vb the AddRange would work but I have had this issue before doing conversion work from VB.NET to C# and you don't need the AddRange

Comment: Thanks... by the way, GetData is not recognized here because it has one parameter (@Material-from the stored procedure) and for some reason, it is called without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataSet CreateReport(String Connectionstring,string StoreProcedureName ,SqlParameter[] Parameter,ref  Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer,string ReportDataSource) {

//return the dataset

}

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
   SelectMethod="CreateReport" TypeName="SqlHelper" />
```

can u try to change ur method return value to DataSet..
and in the codebehind try to databind to that method..

Maybe it might work..

Comment: am just changing the binding from getdata to createreport really.. cud not be of much help but still worth a try because the error is pointing to getdata so was just taking a guess, thts it.. maybe not a real solution, cant tell frm here, it is indeed a little complex n needs more time to resolve, trying to get the most basic thing out of the way and see if all the complex things fall in place..