# ASP.NET report with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure named "Graph" that should get a value to the parameter @Material, and I created a report in ASP.NET that should show a chart using the data from the stored procedure.

However, when I try to load the report I get:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'PhilipsMaterialsDataSet'.
>   ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'GetData' that has no parameters.

I tried different solutions but none of them worked. Also, I'm not sure if I should declare the parameter in the ASP code.

( by the way, GetData is not recognized here because it has one parameter (@Material-from the stored procedure) and for some reason, it is called without any parameters )

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;


public partial class StatisticsPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string Connectionstring = "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }

    }

   protected void btndisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindReport();
    }
    private void BindReport()
    {
        SSRSReport report = new SSRSReport();
        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
         new SqlParameter("@Material","453567068441")

      };
        string ReportDataSource = "DataSet1";
        bool bind = report.CreateReport(Connectionstring, "graph", sqlParams, ref ReportViewer1, ReportDataSource);
        if (bind)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}


public class SSRSReport
{


       public SSRSReport()
       {
              //
              // TODO: Add constructor logic here
              //
       }
    public bool CreateReport(String Connectionstring,string StoreProcedureName ,SqlParameter[] Parameter,ref  Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer,string ReportDataSource)
    {
        bool reportbind = false;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = StoreProcedureName;
            com.Parameters.AddRange(Parameter);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(ReportDataSource, ds.Tables[0]);
            if ( ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);





                //This is another solution I tried:





                //List<ReportParameter> lstReportParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
                //ReportParameter objReportParameter = new ReportParameter("Material", "453567068441");
                //lstReportParameters.Add(objReportParameter);
                //ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(lstReportParameters);
               // ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();

                reportbind = true;
            }                       
        }
       return  reportbind;
    }

}
```

The ASP code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StatisticsPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="StatisticsPage" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test SSRS</title>
</head>
<body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="610px" Width="1179px" ShowParameterPrompts="true">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc" >
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="PhilipsMaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.GraphTableAdapter" >
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
          </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than post your page class code, could you post the GetData method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET report with parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470646/asp-net-report-with-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying GetData requires some parameters, and you have to supply them by adding a parameters like like:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="PhilipsMaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.GraphTableAdapter" >
   <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="X" DefaultValue="Y" .. />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the report can be loaded but I get: "No Data Available" I added: <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Material"/>
        </SelectParameters>

Comment: OK.  You have to supply a value by adding a DefaultValue.  You can set the default value in code to be what you need it to.  The default value is the value supplied to the function.  Or look at the other parameters like ControlParameter, SessionParameter, which have more functionality than the default.